# extra rows in merged data frames pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I trying to merge 2 data frames. The frames do not share columns (except the keys). So merging should just add columns of the right to the left. However, I am also getting extra rows. I don't understand where the 2 extra rows come from.

If I use left_index and right_index then it would have worked perfect. However, I don't understand how normal merging on keys would have 2 extra rows like in my result. Thanks

```
dat1 = np.array([['Afghanistan', 2007, 'new_ep_m1524', 0],['Afghanistan', 2007, 'new_sn_m65', 0],
              ['Afghanistan', 2012, 'new_sn_f014', 1190],['Afghanistan', 2011, 'new_sn_f014', 851],
              ['Afghanistan', 2013, 'newrel_m014', 1705]], dtype=object)

dat2 = np.array([['ep', 'male', '15-24', 'Afghanistan', 2007],['sn', 'male', '65+', 'Afghanistan', 2007],
              ['sn', 'female', '0-14', 'Afghanistan', 2012],['sn', 'female', '0-14', 'Afghanistan', 2011],
              ['rel', 'male', '0-14', 'Afghanistan', 2013]], dtype=object)

left = pd.DataFrame(data=dat1, columns=['country', 'year', 'case_type', 'count'] ) 

rigt = pd.DataFrame(data=dat2, columns=['type', 'gender', 'age_group', 'country', 'year'])


display(left), display(right) 
pd.merge(left,right, on=['country', 'year'], how='outer')
```

left
[image]

right
[image]

result
[image]

Comment: Thanks all for the answers  I know the reason now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have keys that are repeated in your dataset. `Afghanistan 2007` has two rows in each data frame. When merging with a full outer join, it is not clear which of the two records `Afghanistan 2007` should match between the two data frames. So, both are joined. This is why there are four records with `Afghanistan 2007` in the merged data frame (2 from the first data frame + 2 from the second data frame).

Answer (score 0):

Your merging is on the column year, which is not unique for each row.

The merging associates the row 0 of the left dataframe with the rows 0 and 1 of the right dataframe, and the row 1 of the left dataframe with the rows 0 and 1 of the right dataframe.

To avoid that you could remove the case_type or add a unique id according to your needs.